# Node js Web api doesn't send an error if the price is lower than 0

Tags: node.js, api-design

I've recently created a simple node js web api which is connected to a MySql database, in my database I have a price parameter which has to be equal or more than 0, I added a check into my product.service but it returns an empty error request:

```
{
    "error": {}
}
```

My service check looks like this:

```
async function createProduct(params){
    if(await db.Product.findOne({where: {name: params.name}})){
        throw 'Such a product already exists, please try again';
    }

    if(params.price < 0){
        throw 'The price of the product cannot be null, please try again';
    }

    const product = new db.Product(params);

    await product.save();
}
```

My product.controller looks like this:

```
router.post('/', createSchema,createProduct);

function createProduct(req, res, next){
    productService.createProduct(req.body)
    .then(() => res.json({message: '{Product was succesfuly created!'}))
    .catch(next);
}

function createSchema(req, res, next){
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        price: Joi.number().min(0).max(99999999.99).precision(2).required()
    });

    validateRequest(req, next, schema);
}
```

Comment: Where is `createProduct` used?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a request